# How to display value from cell in vba code?

Tags: vba

`Row_No = 5`

`MsgBox Range.("A & Row_No").value`

i have above code but it gives me error `1004`..please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

**Just try this**

```
MsgBox Range.("A" & Row_No).Value
```

**or this**

```
MsgBox Range.("A" & Row_No).Text
```

**or this**

```
MsgBox Cells(1,"C")
```

Problem with the code you used is nothing but placing of `&` and `"` in wrong place.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Better also try without the "." after `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

When doing concatenation, keep in mind that strings will be in quotes and variables will not -- think of the quotes as telling the compiler to interpret what is between them as literal text.  A good IDE will usually indicate this via syntax highlighting.

So, in your code, the `Range()` method is being passed the string `A & Row_No` instead of `A5` -- so it errors out.